# Why isn't my neural network training method being called? (ML5.JS)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a doodle recognition neural network using ml5js. 
Using [Google's Quick, Draw Data Set](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/data) to train my neural network.

This is my first attempt at doing anything machine learning so I am a noobie to this.

In essence, I want a user to draw/sketch something in a canvas, press the guess button, and the neural network guesses what they drew. *E.g. they draw a bike, press **guess**, and the neural network guesses that the picture is a bike.*

To start off with, I downloaded the data of [cat doodles](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/_details/quickdraw_dataset/full/simplified/cat.ndjson) from Google's data set.

To be specific, I want to:

1. Load in my loads of cat drawings. (These come from local .ndjson files)

```
    let unformattedFile;

    let jsonFormattedFile = {
    "data": [

      ]
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { //hard code 1000
        jsonFormattedFile["data"].push(
            { "xs": { "drawing": unformattedFile[i].drawing }, "ys": { "word": unformattedFile[i].word } }
        )
    }
```

2. Teach my neural network that these are what cat drawings look like (providing the strokes that the drawings have as inputs).

```
neuralNetwork = ml5.neuralNetwork(options);

    //Start to add Data to the NN
    for (let x = 0; x < jsonFormattedFile.data.length; x++) {

        let inputs = {
            xs: jsonFormattedFile.data[x].xs
        }

        let target = {
            ys: jsonFormattedFile.data[x].ys
        }

        neuralNetwork.data.addData(inputs, target);
    }
        neuralNetwork.data.normalize();

    function whileTraining(epoch, loss) {
        console.log(`epoch: ${epoch}, loss:${loss}`);
    }

    function doneTraining() {
        makeClassification();
    }

    neuralNetwork.train(whileTraining, doneTraining);
```

3. Test the neural network with a cat doodle and make sure it works.

```
    newTest = jsonFormattedFile.data[0].xs;

    neuralNetwork.classify([newTest], (err, results) => {
        console.log(results);

        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    });
```

The issue I discovered while debugging was that the whileTraining() never does anything... it doesn't print anything to the console which I assume is causing my neural network to not train.

This causes me to get the error:
...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'predict' of null
```

...When I ask the neural network to classify my test doodle in step 3.

I am looking for some help on how to properly train my neural network. I am finding it very difficult to start off in ML :(

Comment: Is step 3 inside the `makeClassification` function?

Comment: @Jacob yes, sorry I didn't make that clear - the code in step 3 is the makeClassification function.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the ML5 repo, and found out that `whileTraining` will never be called when you set `debug: true` for your NeuralNetwork options. It is odd, but that is the reason why `whileTraining` isn't called.